# Ribbon Button Not Working In Home Page (Home.aspx) And Any Site Pages

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions

I've created a "Hello World" ribbon button as per MSDN code sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630938.aspx

The "Hello World" ribbon button is working only in AllItems.aspx (i.e. In the left navigation pane, click "Shared Documents" to open the Shared Documents library.). However, the "Hello World" ribbon button is not visible in the following scenarios:

1. "Shared Document" on the homepage (i.e home.aspx) - At Home.aspx, edit page, click on "Insert" tab, click on "Existing List" and then add "Shared Documents" list into the page.
2. "Shared Document" on any site page - Create new site page, click edit page, click on "Insert" tab, click on "Existing List" and then add "Shared Documents" list into the page.

I have full permissions to the site, however the "Hello World" ribbon button is still not visible to me. Is this a SharePoint bug?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but it can be because of settings of ListViewWebpart on your page. If the toolbar in this webpart settings is set to Summary mode the Ribbon customizations for the underlying list will not be displayed on page. You need to set it to Full mode.

Comment: Setting the toolbar to Full did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've created a Ribbon Custom Action which only attaches to Lists (see RegistrationType=List), and not Web Part Contextual Groups. When you add the Shared Documents view to a page, it's added to a Web Part.

You'll need to look at adding your button to the Contextual Tab Group for the Web Part as well as the List itself. Here's lots of info on MSDN about Contextual Tab Groups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx and also on Chris O'Brien's blog: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html